# What might cause Eclipse to not run after Windows BSOD?

Tags: java, eclipse, bsod

After BSOD in Windows 10, Eclipse (Neon & Indigo) splash screens flash and then nothing. Prior to this both were working perfectly.

I tried deleting all folders related to Eclipse (including workspaces), downloading and extracting fresh zip files. I've tried many of the solutions related to "Splash screen and Eclipse not starting".

The only additional piece of information I get is when I try `eclipsec.exe -clean`. It returns:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

So far none of the recommendations for this error work either. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you verified that your JREs/JDKs are alright?

Comment: I uninstalled/reinstalled my JDK, and everything is back to normal! Many thanks @nitind ! I had verified all paths, java_home, etc. but didn't occur to me that something had happened to the installation. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your Eclipse IDE was working fine before the BSOD, it's safe to conclude that your JDK/JRE were affected. BSOD issues have been known to affect JDK and/or JRE. Re-install both, after which you should restart your IDE.

Everything should be fine after that. I hope this helps.. Merry coding!